# how to create two rows with responsive images with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I want to create a card games with bootstrap 4 and Vue but I am not a great front-end developer.
I would like to create two rows with responsive rounded images inside but I am unable to do that. Both rows should have an height of 25%.

This is the code of my component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row h-25">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
        <div class="row h-25">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" class="card img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is my stylesheet:

```
.card {
    border-radius: 10%;
}
```

The images are correctly rounded but they are not responsive. I tried removing the class row in the div but the images aren't responsive as well.
Is someone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `rounded-circle` bootstrap class in your image class.

To explain what `rounded-circle` does

```
.rounded-circle {
    border-radius: 50%!important;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the images remain not responsive as well.